# Rate limit for traefik using json data from request

Tags: parsing, traefik, rate-limiting

I'd like to set rateLimit for requests where in json data present param with sample value

Example

```
curl -X 'POST'   'http://127.0.0.1/'   -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost   -H 'accept: application/json'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{
  "sender": "Tester",
  "receiver": [
    "receiver1" 
  ],
  "text": "Text",
  "service": "service" 
}'
```

I need limit 100rps for sender=Tester, other senders must have no rateLimit

I tried such config:

```
[http.routers]
   [http.routers.whoami_1]
      rule = "Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)&&Query(sender=Tester)"
      service = "whoami"
      entrypoints = ["web"]
      middlewares = ["test-ratelimit"]

[http.middlewares]
  [http.middlewares.test-ratelimit.rateLimit]
    average = 100
```

But received

```
404 page not found
```

How can I get param from json data in request and set rule for routes or middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traefik does not provide middlewares to extract the JSON payload from the request.

You can probably try to [create a custom plugin](https://github.com/traefik/plugindemo#local-mode) extracting the value and applying the rate limiting on its own.